# how to install this particular package Texinfo

Tags: installation, makefile, package, texinfo

Hello i am trying to install a package called Texinfo on debian 10.3 running with kernel 4.19.94-ti-r42. The readme states the following:

```
 texinfo.tex and the other *.tex files are not installed by
  `make install', because there is no reliable way to know where to
  install them.  Instead, you have to run an additional make command
  after the normal make install:
    make TEXMF=/your/texmf install-tex
  texinfo.tex is installed in ${TEXMF}/tex/texinfo/texinfo.tex, etc.
```

To me, it seems to be saying that i have to run the make command twice, however when i try:

```
debian@beaglebone:~/texinfo-6.7$ make TEXMF=/your/texmf install-tex
```

i get this error:

```
make: *** No rule to make target 'install-tex'.  Stop.
```

Perhaps the "your" in the command has to be replaced with something else?

Answer (score 0):

The solution in the link below solved my problem:
https://www.linux.co.cr/ldp/lfs/chapter06/texinfo.html